# Version Control Menu Definition in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, version-control, xamarin-studio

I am working on github with Xamarin Studio. But I can't find some Menu word Meaning and what is its Uses. I search on google and xamarin documentation but I couldn't find it.

The Menu Word is

1. Version Control > Lock File
2. Version Control > Unlock File
3. Versoin Control > Add to ignore List
4. Version Control > Remove From ignore List

Comment: You are working with an Subversion (`svn`) repo and not a `git` repo. Free Subversion ebook : http://svnbook.red-bean.com Lock/Unlock is used to obtain and release an exclusive lock on a file so others can not modify the same file in a shared repo. Svn ignore lists are used to determine which files are under version control or not...

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for the response and link.